# Javascript Split Performance

Tags: javascript, split, performance

I'm sure you've all seen code like this in JS:

```
var args = 'now later today tomorrow'.split(' ')
```

Anyone know why that's faster than this:

```
args = ['now', 'later', 'today', 'tomorrow']
```

(I don't know the answer to this, but I can verify by timing in the console that splitting is faster)

Comment: If you look at Decad's jsperf, I see the second one as massively faster than the first (in Chrome) which makes logical sense.  For you to get any meaningful answers, you'll have to share what data you have and how you collected it that shows the first to ever be faster.

Comment: It's smaller which can help in minifying (e.g. jQuery uses this for creating functions like `.click`, `.mouseover`, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Would be surprised if it was faster, could you post how you came to think it is?

I made this perf quickly and It shows its not faster.

http://jsperf.com/split-performance

Comment: Your right the split is much much slower, ecspcially on a larger set.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the javascript engine you were using has deferred execution capabilities and so the actual splitting didn't occur yet? Try timing again in the console but included accessing the first member of the split array.